# angularJSのCSRF対策をしたい

Tags: angularjs, security, cookie

以下のサイトに書いてある通りにangularJSのCSRF対策をしたいと考えています。
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http
そこで以下のサイトを参考にしてCookieにトークンを保存しようとしました。
https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/docs/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies

```
$cookies.XSRF-TOKEN = data['token'];
```

しかしこれでは

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
```

というエラーがでてできませんでした。
おそらくXSRF-TOKENが悪いのだと考えていますがこの場合どのようにして解決すればいいのでしょうか。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XSRF-TOKENが引き算でないのなら

```
$cookies['XSRF-TOKEN'] = data['token'];
```

と書けばいいと思いますが

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。その記法はもちろん試しましたが、質問文のURLにあるとおり1.3では記法が変わっているようなので使えませんでした。

Comment: エラーが出ることが問題ではないのですか？具体的になにがどう’使えなかった’のか書いてもらえないでしょうか。

Comment: 申し訳ありません。教えてくださったコードで試してみたところ、できました。ありがとうございます。